# Automatically Converting Natural Language to First-Order Logic

Tags: nlp

I'm trying to find a way to automatically convert arbitrary natural language sentences into first-order logic predicates. Although complex, this seems to be feasible to me, through [inverse lambda calculus](http://www.public.asu.edu/~cbaral/papers/fol2012.pdf); one of the biggest downsides of this technique is that it heavily relies on a combinatory categorial grammar (CCG), which must be trained to yield the appropriate results.

Are there other known approaches to such conversion at all, or it is a bad idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**... it heavily relies on a combinatory categorial grammar (CCG), which must be trained...**

There are two broad-coverage CCG parsers for English, which you could use:

1. [Curran & Clark Parser](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sc609/candc-1.00.html) by itself only generates CCG derivations with *categories*, not with semantics. [Boxer](https://valeriobasile.github.io/candcapi/) works on the parses to generate semantics.
2. [OpenCCG](https://github.com/OpenCCG/openccg) when used with the broad-coverage grammar, [MOLOKO](http://talkingrobots.dfki.de/software/tarot/) can show semantics. But I haven't used this one yet, and can't read their output.

**Are there other approaches...**

CCG is not the only logic-based grammar. There are others that closer to mathematics, in that, their derivation trees for sentences that look exactly like [natural deduction proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction). I think the [ACG guys](http://www.loria.fr/equipes/calligramme/acg/) have a working parser. I am not sure about the others like TLG, CVG, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the [Boxer](http://svn.ask.it.usyd.edu.au/trac/candc/wiki/boxer) parser is broken now.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Thanks for notifying me. I have updated the links.

Comment: @prash. It looks like C&C and Boxer are missing final piece from DRS to FOL.

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to convert natural language into first-order logic using a [discourse representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_representation_theory). For example, the [ACE reasoner](http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/race/) is an automated theorem prover that can convert English text into first-order logical predicates.

Comment: But if I understand correctly, we need to convert English to ACE language first and only then we can get first order logic representation.